# Create modal popup in NetSuite

Tags: javascript, popup, netsuite, clientscript

I have a requirement to show modal popup on  in netsuite on button click.
currently I open a window using client script

```
var url =  nlapiResolveURL('SUITELET','customscript_id','customdeploy_id',null);
window.open(url);
```

Now I want to make this window as modal popup to prevent accessing the parent window. Please help.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use existing solutions like 
[Bootsrap](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) or Jquery UI's [Modal Window](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

If you want to be more elegant and avoid dependencies, you can create your own light implementation. Please, refer to [how to make window.open pop up Modal?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801124/how-to-make-window-open-pop-up-modal)

Comment: You can add any applicable framework as a library on your existing client script.