# How to open external source as dialog in Dynamics CRM

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-crm-2016

I want to open dialog in Dynamics CRM with javascript function, for internal sources I use:

```
function openModalForm(url) {

    var DialogOption = new Xrm.DialogOptions();
    DialogOption.width = 500;
    DialogOption.height = 260;
    Xrm.Internal.openDialog(url, DialogOption, null, null);

}
```

Now I need to open external urls like: `url = 'http://www.yahoo.com/'`

How could I open the external sources as dialog in Dynamics? any idea?

Comment: window.showModalDialog work for you?

Answer (score 1):

Essentially you are looking for a common method to open a browser window as a modal popup. Modern browsers do not support this anymore and it can only be achieved with some tricks/libs/workarounds (e.g. see [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24801124/how-to-make-window-open-pop-up-modal).)

Personally I have given up on this and accept that `window.open()` just opens windows modeless. A better technique would be modal CSS-dialogs, which in modern web development would be the preferred way to go. However, in Dynamics CRM custom CSS dialogs require fiddling with the DOM, which is not a supported customization.

Answer (score 0):

You can embed an IFRAME into your CRM form named, for example `new_iframecontainer`.

Then on load of your form, you can use the `Xrm` function [`setSrc`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266.aspx#BKMK_setSrc) like so:

```js
Xrm.Page.getControl("new_iframecontainer").setSrc("www.yahoo.com");
```

---

An alternative solution would be to pass an encoded URL to an HTML web resource using `openWebResource`. Then in the HTML web resource, redirect to the URL that was passed. [This blog post](https://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/crmtipsfromadeveloper/archive/2017/06/19/know-how-mscrm-open-external-url-using-xrm-utility-openwebresource-d365) covers how this approach can be acheived.

Comment: Thank you! the problem is for both solutions there not like dialog, it is like the iframe in the page or new window